# Mass Variable Decimal Places PHP

Tags: php, numbers, decimal

I know you can tell a variable to go to a certain number of decimal places using:

```
string number_format ( float $number [, int $decimals = 3 ] )
```

However, I cannot find a way of doing this en masse for all numbers. Since I have hundreds of variables, all of which need to have the same number of decimal places (whether it means rounding or extending zeros), I would like to be able to just tell it to automatically perform this command across the board instead of typing in the above command for all variables.

Does this function exist, or am I forced to type it all out the long way? Is there maybe a line in the .ini file that I could change if there is no command?

Thanks in advance.

---

I'm not storing these numbers in a database - I'm echo-ing them on the screen and sending an email.

(There is an equation going on from user input being generated by an HTML form).

The person receiving the email has asked that all numbers be rounded to the third decimal, whether that means rounding off at the thousandths or extending zeros to the thousandths if it only needed whole numbers, tenths, or hundredths. There are literally hundreds of individual variables, i.e. $number1, $number2, etc.

Comment: can you define "all numbers", what are these numbers and where do they come from?

Comment: This mght be relatively interesting: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: what do you mean by hundreds of variables? are they all random names? or are they in one array?

Comment: Define a custom function that you apply to all your values...? Use a loop to format many values with one line of code...? I'm very unclear on what exactly the issue is here.

Comment: I'm not storing these numbers in a db - I'm echo-ing them on the screen and sending an email. (There is an equation going on from user input being generated by an HTML form). The person receiving the email has asked that all numbers be rounded to the third decimal, whether that means rounding off at the thousandths or extending zeros to the thousandths if it only needed whole numbers, tenths, or hundredths. There are literally hundreds of individual variables, i.e. $number1, $number2, etc.

Comment: it is better to edit your question than to put details in comments. I have updated your question for you

Comment: Thanks for the forum info. I'll test your answer and mark as correct when I can get it to work.

Comment: If you have "hundreds of individual variables", especially if those are literally called `$number1`, `$number2` etc, you seriously need to work on your data structures. Use an array to store all your numbers, then it's trivial to *iterate over the array* and format all your numbers at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about all numbers applied to string variables in your script you could run this line:

```
if(is_int($value) || is_float($value)){
    $value = number_format ( float $number ,3 );
}
```

Obviously as you reference *strings* you can also run a similar query to check if your string is a floating numeric:

```
$values = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($values as $key=>$value){
     if(is_string($value) && (float)$value == (string)$value){
        $value = number_format ((float)$value , 3 );
    }
   /***
    Save over the original script variables with the edited ones.
    Note double dollar
    ***/
   $$key = $value;
}
unset($values,$value,$key);
```

You could do with reading that in base-2 (computer storage) floating point numbers are inherently stored inaccurately, read http://floating-point-gui.de/ .

Also, really, why would you need this seemingly needless precision?

But then at what stage do you run this command, at the start of your script when the values are mostly empty? Or at the end when the values are mostly been used and no longer active?

I think my answer answers your question but I think that your question does not actually articulate your issue.

---

In response to the comment / edited qestion:

Simply rather than using `$values = get_defined_vars();` use the values from saving the inputs into an array and doing `foreach` above through the array.

```
$values = array(array of numbers);
foreach ($values as &$value){
     if(is_string($value) && (float)$value == (string)$value){
        $value = number_format ((float)$value , 3 );
    }
}
unset($value,$key);
```

This will update all values in the array to being of the spcified numerical placements.

Comment: This is a re-paste from my comment above to clarify my need:


 
I'm not storing these numbers in a db - I'm echo-ing them on the screen and sending an email. (There is an equation going on from user input being generated by an HTML form). The person receiving the email has asked that all numbers be rounded to the third decimal, whether that means rounding off at the thousandths or extending zeros to the thousandths if it only needed whole numbers, tenths, or hundredths. There are literally hundreds of individual variables, i.e. $number1, $number2, etc.

Comment: I have edited my answer for you. Basically, use an array @sparrowhawk87

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [decimal](http://php-decimal.io) extension to achieve this, with a central place to create and format. Something like this:

```
class Number 
{
    public static function create($value, $precision = Decimal::DEFAULT_PRECISION): Decimal
    {
        return new Decimal($value, $precision);
    } 

    public static function format(Decimal $decimal, int $places = 3): string
    {
        return $decimal->toFixed(3);
    }
}
```